# Test MagSafe charger without computer?

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

I have a MacBook Air, 2013-era, that will not charge. Plugging it into the charger briefly causes the "battery is dead, plug in" graphic to show up on the screen. The connection seems pretty solid and I can't see any objects in the port or plug.

The light on the charger never lights up. Is there any way to eliminate the charger as the cause of the problem? I have no other machine to test it with.

Comment: Where are you?  An answer asks about your area and an Apple store.  Can you update your question?  Should we edit the question to say that you don't want to take the computer and/or/charger to certain places.

Comment: Are you sure the AC adapter is powerful enough for the MacBook you have?  I have a MacBook Pro that needed more power than my older smaller MacBook.  When I go to group coding events I have to be careful that I go home with the same adapter that I arrived with.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an Apple store in the area where you can take both the charger and Mac and have them test each?

Best Buy (especially, including Geek Squad) or office supply stores can probably also test both parts, and often the local schools (especially high school art dept.) will have Apple devices and maybe your library too - anywhere someone might have similar devices and parts to help check your pieces out.

Comment: I went to the Apple store - mystery solved, coffee in machine, two weeks out of warranty, more to fix than buy new, :-(